# Fail assembly if file is too large in gnu as

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

I am trying to assemble a file whose binary must fit in a specific size. I’ve been trying to see if there was a way for the assembler to fail if it’s too big so that I know. I was thinking something like:

```
.if . > 0x200
.error “binary too large”
.endif
```

But this doesn’t work as the if express is not absolute. I tried doing it with a label as well but it also doesn’t work. Is there a way to do this with directives or within as?

Comment: Is this for a bootloader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently if you set the current address to something less than it should be, the assembling will fail. So concluding the file with

```
. = 0x200
```

Causes `as` to throw an error if the file was larger then that.

Edit: As pointed out by @fuz, this will pad the file to that size, I don’t have an answer if this is an issue for you.

Comment: Note that this will pad your binary to that size which might not be what you want.

Comment: @fuz yeah I know. Personally I am ok with this but I’m going to edit the answer so thy if someone else sees it they know.

Comment: I can write  a proper answer for this later.  The trick is to use an if directive with an absolute value gained by taking the difference between two labels.

Comment: @fuz : I thought about writing an answer until I learned that for some reason subtracting a label from the current location counter (or even the difference between two labels) in the same section results in an error suggesting the value isn't absolute. Both labels were defined before the check was done, so even a single pass assembler like `as` should have been able to figure it out. I didn't try earlier versions of binutils to see if it has always been this way. It smelled like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

Querying segment size at assembly time during the last pass seemed useful to me, that's why the attribute **SIZE#** is able to retrieve this information in EuroAssembler.

So if you don't insist on *GNU as*, this works:

```
binary PROGRAM
%AllowedSize %SETA 9
[DATA] SEGMENT         ; Common segment for code and data.
  DB "1234567890"      ; Example of data contents.
  %IF SIZE# [DATA] > %AllowedSize
    %ERROR Size of program "binary" exceeds %AllowedSize.
  %ENDIF
  ENDPROGRAM
```